# How to GET external url inside django views

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to get some page to parse its json content from within a views, using [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html).

Here is what I tried:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import urllib2

def someviews(request):
    url = some_external_url
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    return the_page.content
```

However, I get `HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway` at

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

What could be wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easier with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests 

def someviews(request):
    url = some_external_url        
    return requests.get(url).json()
```

but the 502 seems to be the other end's fault

Comment: Nice but it gives `'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'`

Comment: @ultrax what does `print requests.get(url).content` give you?